# Mapping fields on Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to re-map a certain field in Python, but not sure how to go about it. The topic is regarding gravitational lensing. So what i've done upto now is obtain a deflection field, which tells you how light is bent around masses.[Deflection Field Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQeLH.png)

Using this, I obtained something called a magnification map, which shows you the regions that would produce the brightest images. The redder the color, the brighter the image.[Magnification Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfEkP.png) Now, I want to subtract the deflection field from the magnification map to obtain another mapping in a different plane.

I'm not sure how to go about this, since my deflection field is a 2d vector, so I have the deflection_x and deflection_y as 2 arrays. My magnification meanwhile is just values assigned to each grid point in a 2d X-Y grid. Another way to re-phrase what I'm trying to do is as follows. Let the magnification be I.

So right now I have I(x,y). I want to obtain I(x - (deflection_x), y -(deflection_y)). Basically it takes the curve in orange and makes it into another curve in the new x and y positions but with the same magnitude. I've given my current code below:

```
x = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
y = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
zeta_a = (-3,0)
zeta_b = (3,0)
def get_dist_squared(x_array, y_array):
return x_array**2 + y_array**2 
M_a= 150
M_b= 150
G = 1
c = 1
zeta_min_zeta_a_x = X - zeta_a[0] 
zeta_min_zeta_a_y = Y - zeta_a[1]
zeta_min_zeta_b_x = X - zeta_b[0]
zeta_min_zeta_b_y = Y - zeta_b[1]
dist_zeta_min_zeta_a = get_dist_squared(zeta_min_zeta_a_x,zeta_min_zeta_a_y)
dist_zeta_min_zeta_b = get_dist_squared(zeta_min_zeta_b_x,zeta_min_zeta_b_y)
alpha_x = M_a * zeta_min_zeta_a_x / dist_zeta_min_zeta_a
alpha_x  += M_b * zeta_min_zeta_b_x / dist_zeta_min_zeta_b 
alpha_x *= 4 * G / (c**2) 
alpha_y = M_a * zeta_min_zeta_a_y / dist_zeta_min_zeta_a
alpha_y += M_b * zeta_min_zeta_b_y / dist_zeta_min_zeta_b
alpha_y *= 4 * G / (c**2)
alpha_x_y, alpha_x_x = np.gradient(alpha_x,edge_order=1)
alpha_y_y, alpha_y_x = np.gradient(alpha_y,edge_order=1)
det_A = 1 - alpha_y_y - alpha_x_x + (alpha_x_x)*(alpha_y_y) - (alpha_x_y)*(alpha_y_x)
abs = np.absolute(det_A)
I = abs**(-1.)
```

The magnification is given by I. Don't worry about the calculation part of the code, what I want after this step is to subtract alpha_x and alpha_y from I. alpha_x and alpha_y are the deflections in the x and y axes.

From what I've tried, simply doing I - alpha_x and I - alpha_y and plotting this does not help. It is not the value of the magnification that should be subtracted, but simply the positions of the magnifications.

Thanks! I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: One point I did not understood is if you want translation of your image (So point I(x,y) will now be in I(x-alpha_x, y-alpha_y)) or a new calculation of I for the point x-alpha_x, y-alpha_y. If its the the first option this is a plotting issue and it can be done easily with any number of the plot engines around. If its the latter you'll going to have to state how you want your new I values to be "estimated" (since they don't exist).

Comment: @ armatita, the I values remain the same, it is simply the positions that need to be translated to the new coordinates. Each I(x,y) needs to now be I(x- alpha_x, y- alpha_y), but the "I" would be the same. So I'm guessing this is equivalent to the first option, but how would one go about doing this?
@Benjamin, I have already used meshgrid, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just simply had to subtract directly from the np.meshgrid and then replot I with respect to the new coordinate system. Guess I just got confused because of all the components involved. Thanks for your help!